# Is it possible to convert a list of `integral_constant`s back to a list of `T`'s?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I managed to convert a `template<int ...Args> struct List` to a list of `integral_constant`'s, however, is it possible to convert from `integral_constant`'s back to `int`s?

Here is how I do the conversion from `IntList` to `List`:

```
template<typename ...Args>
struct List;

template<typename T>
struct ListFromTupleImpl;
template<typename ...Args>
struct ListFromTupleImpl<std::tuple<Args...>>
{ using type = List<Args...>; };

template<typename T>
using ListFromTuple = typename ListFromTupleImpl<T>::type;
template<typename ...Args>
using TupleCat = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<Args>()...));
template<typename ...Args>
using ListFromTupleCat = ListFromTuple<TupleCat<Args...>>;

template<int ...Args>
struct IntList;

template<typename ...Args>
struct List
{
    template<typename T>
    struct Concat;
    template<typename ...Args0>
    struct Concat<List<Args0...>>
    {
        using type = ListFromTupleCat<std::tuple<Args...>,
                                      std::tuple<Args0...>>;
    };
};

template<int ...Args>
struct IntList
{
    template<int first, int ...Args0>
    struct ListBuilder
    {
        using type = typename List<std::integral_constant<int, first>>::
                    template Concat<typename ListBuilder<Args0...>::type>::type;
    };
    template<int last>
    struct ListBuilder<last>
    {
        using type = List<std::integral_constant<int, last>>;
    };
    using asList = typename ListBuilder<Args...>::type;
};
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0Zd3MTDiZYBrZpMb)?

Comment: @krzaq No, it should be of type `IntList`, not `std::array`

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now.

Comment: @krzaq Related question would be: "How to concat two `IntList`s?" If you can archive that, then it'd be easy to solve my problem.

Comment: Is [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KgE1nYzB03XZBD3t) what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want by letting the compiler match template patterns:

```
template<typename... Ts>
auto to_int_list_helper(List<Ts...>) {
    return IntList<Ts::value...>{};
}

template<typename ListParam>
using AsIntList = decltype(to_int_list_helper(ListParam{}));
```

and a proof of concept:

```
using L = typename IntList<1,2>::asList;

static_assert(is_same<L, List<integral_constant<int, 1>, integral_constant<int, 2>>>::value, "");

using BackToIntList = AsIntList<L>;

static_assert(is_same<IntList<1,2>, BackToIntList>::value, "");
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KgE1nYzB03XZBD3t)

Since you also asked about concatenation, it's really simple to leverage the same technique:

```
template<int... Ts, int... Us>
auto concat_int_lists_helper(IntList<Ts...>, IntList<Us...>) {
    return IntList<Ts..., Us...>{};
}

template<typename A, typename B>
using ConcatIntLists = decltype(concat_int_lists_helper(A{}, B{}));
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FFSq93Gnd4BFA7Cs)

Comment: @NaCl Glad to help. Added concatenation example, but you should be able to write your own already :)